# fs.existsSync is not a function node.js/electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

i am getting the error from a dependency (electron-edge) of an electron/node js app. The node.js version is 5.5.0 and electron version is 0.36.7

Comment: `fs.existsSync()` has been deprecated.   See [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) for alternatives.

Comment: so i guess i have to wait for an update on the electron-edge module

Comment: i downgraded to node.js v0.12.10 as on this version the existsSync method isn't deprecated [link](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.12.10/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) but i get the same error. As i have no previous experience with node.js and electron maybe i am missing some basic stuff here regarding node.js setup and its api

Comment: Can you explain more about the error?  What is the EXACT error message and in what circumstance do you get the error (e.g. what are you doing at the time you get the error)?

Comment: Where are you checking the node version? It doesn't matter what node version you have in your system. Electron has its own node. Inside the dev console you can check the node version that comes with the electron version you are using with process.versions.

Comment: i found that it has something to do with the browserify component that i am using for bundling. I know that bundling is not needed as electron is able to load modules dynamically but in the same time i was playing around with react/flex framework and i was using the bundling step to also transpile the jsx sources. The conclusion is that is nothing wrong with the node version. I am looking for a better build model to transpile jsx in my app.

Answer (score 6):

To complete Mark Meyer answer : if you're using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) with electron, you cannot modify webpack without ejecting create-react-app. Here is a solution using [@craco/craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) :

```
npm i --save @craco/craco
```

Replace create-react-app by craco in your package.json scripts :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
```

Add craco.config.js to the root directory

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: {
            target: 'electron-renderer'
        }
    }
};
```

Modify your main.js file:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
  {
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      webPreferences: {        // add
        nodeIntegration: true  // these
      }                        // lines
  });
```

Then from you js file, to open file dialog for example, use window.require :

```
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(remote.getCurrentWindow(), {properties:["openDirectory"]});
```

See [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6782) issue for the full story

Comment: This is the solution I have been looking for in whole internet.
I wonder why this answer didnt get the upvotes. 
I am working on a simple app using create-react-app and publish it to windows using electron

I have some api calls that need to use NTLM authentication. I was facing this weird issue since long. I knew that ejecting CRA and making some changes to it was the solution, but I didnt want to unbundle the whole react setup in my dev environment.
These simple instructions and craco package did the magic !
  
I am really thankful to you !

Comment: you probably want to use `contextBridge` instead of `nodeIntegration: true`, see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using a bundler for your code. In this case, the problem arises, because you don't bundle with the correct target set.

In webpack include `target: 'electron-renderer'` into your `webpack.config.js`.

In parcel bundle with the correct target via the command line option `--target electron` (`parcel build yourfile.html --target electron`).