# Importing electron through requirejs

Tags: electron, requirejs

I know there are a lot of these posts out there but I can't fix it so this is my best shot.

I am using electron to make a desktop wrapper for my Ionic React app.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
 > electron
      > src
          - index.ts
          > splashScreen
              - splashScreen.ts
      > assets
          - splash.html
          > scripts
              - splash.js
```

In `index.ts` I create a new instance of splash screen. It loads the html file from `assets/splash.html`.

The html includes a div elements called `loading_text` which is where the text for the splash screen needs to go. I am using events via `ipcMain` to control what the div shows. So in `SplashScreen.ts`, the `setText` function is this:

```
function setText(text: string) {
    ipcMain.emit(events.SPLASH_SCREEN_TEXT_CHANGE, text)
}
```

and in `splash.js` I listen for that event like this:

```
var _ = require("electron");

var on = _.icpMain.on;
on('OL:SPLASH_SCREEN_TEXT_CHANGE', (event, text) => {
    document.getElementById("loading_text").innerHTML = text;
});
```

This doesn't work because `require` doesn't exist browser side. I've tried lots of things and I still haven't been able to import electron.

I started by trying:

```
webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
}
```

but it sill throws the same error of `require is not defined`. I tried a few other things, the main one being `requireJS`.
I put the JS file under `assets/scripts/` and modified `splash.js` to this:

```
//requirejs.config({
//    baseUrl: '../../node_modules/',
//});


var _ = requirejs(["electron"]);

var on = _.icpMain.on;
on('OL:SPLASH_SCREEN_TEXT_CHANGE', (event, text) => {
    document.getElementById("loading_text").innerHTML = text;
});
```

which just throws the error of `Script error for "electron"`. Going to the requireJS docs it says to check the file for syntax errors but the file isn't actually being loaded: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   electron.js:1`

I've also read through the Node section on the docs but I'm confused on where I should put `require.js` and also what script to put the config in (although that's probably `index.ts`)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. Instead of requirejs, I tried browserify. I bundled `splash.js` and linked in the html. It threw an error of:

```
fs.existsSync is not a function
```

I did some research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681254/fs-existssync-is-not-a-function-node-js-electron-app) SO post, which not only says to use:

```
webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
}
```

but also instead use `window.require` instead of `require`. After doing this I was able to import electron in the script.