# How can I fix: TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipc

I'm coding a CRA + Electron app using playwright to automate a third party web site. I need to use IPC to control the process. It all works with the draft playwright code running in the main process, but now I want to control it via IPC from the renderer process. This is my first attempt at using this stack and I'm lost here. When I added:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
```

to the renderer module, I get this error:

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
getElectronPath
C:/Users/Bruce/Dropbox/Code/ELECTRON/AcesTraderPowerPulse/node_modules/electron/index.js:8
   5 | 
   6 | function getElectronPath () {
   7 |   let executablePath;
>  8 |   if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
   9 |     executablePath = fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8');
  10 |   }
  11 |   if (process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH) {
View compiled
```

Here is my main.js code:

```
const path = require("path");

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // win.loadFile("index.html");
  win.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
  );

  // // Open the DevTools.
  // if (isDev) {
  //   win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: "detach" });
  // }
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

const { firefox } = require('playwright');
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await firefox.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('https//......deleted..............');
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000); //wait 2000 ms
    await page.waitForLoadState('load');

    const input1 = await page.$('[id ="exampleInputEmail1"]'); //unique element in the inspect source
    // const input1 = await page.$('[data-test-id=exampleInputEmail1]'); //unique element in the inspect source
    const email = '...........deleted..............';
    await input1.type(email)
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000); //wait 2000 ms so that the entire email is typed

    const input2 = await page.$('[id ="exampleInputPassword1"]');//unique element in the inspect source
    // const input2 = await page.$('[data-test-id=exampleInputPassword1]');//unique element in the inspect source
    const password = '........deleted.............';
    await input2.type(password)
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000); //wait 2000 ms so that the entire password is typed

    // find the sign in button and click
    await page.click('"Sign In and Continue"')
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000); //wait 2000 ms
    
    // .......more code deleted here........

    // await browser.close(); // commented out to leave the target page up for inspection
  } catch (e) {
    debugger // for dev inspection
  }
})();
```

I'm completely out of my depth here. What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fs.existsSync is not a function node.js/electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681254/fs-existssync-is-not-a-function-node-js-electron-app)

Comment: Note also that `nodeIntegration: true` is also a no-op unless `contextIsolation: false` for Electron >=12